# how to map a message likes "09Mar21 15:58:54.286667" to a timestamp field in filebeat?

Tags: go, elasticsearch, filebeat

I want to map a message likes "09Mar21 15:58:54.286667"  to a timestamp field in filebeat
but I don't know how to do ?

1 My current filebeat is   filebeat-7.10.0-windows-x86_64, how to do it?

2 from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/processor-timestamp.html
the layout is supported in 8.0 , is it necessary to upgrade to 8.0 ?
how to define the layout in  8.0 to map the format likes "09Mar21 15:58:54.286667"

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

## TLDR;

You can use the following pattern:
`02Jan06 15:04:05.000000`

## To understand

All the *`beats` (metricbeat, filebeat, ...) family is written in `Golang`.
So you will need to provide a pattern specific to `Golang` to parse this date string.

`Golang` offer a somewhat surprising way to handle date/time format.

It is based on a specific date, (The 2nd of January 2006 at 3:05:05 PM).
You are to use this reference time an put it to you desired format.

In your specific case

-> `02Jan06 15:04:05.000000`

You can try it out with the following snippet

```golang
package main
import ("fmt"
        "time")

func main() {
    var t = "09Mar21 15:58:54.286667"

    var t2, err = time.Parse("02Jan06 15:04:05.000000", t)
    
    fmt.Println(t, t2, err)
}
```

Comment: is this mean I must use filebeat 8.0?

Comment: I don't think so. Have you tried with your current setup? which version are you using? (add it to your post)

Comment: now i am using filebeat-7.10.0-windows-x86_64

Comment: Have you tried the pattern? Does it work?